# UITableViewController - disable selection

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

How can the ability to select cells in a Cocoa Touch TableView be completely disabled?

I have managed to get my code to a state where selection seems not possible, but if you hold your finger on a cell for a moment or two it will turn blue (selected) until you move off it.

How can it be completely disabled?

Answer (score 23):

See the [allowsSelection](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW6) property of UITableView.

```
myTableView.allowsSelection = NO;
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for that disabled selection of the cell but still keeps the delete option available

Answer (score 1):

from the apple documentation on [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW20)

> Generally, a window delivers UITouch
>   objects (packaged in UIEvent objects)
>   to a gesture recognizer before it
>   delivers them to the attached hit-test
>   view. But there are some subtle
>   detours and dead-ends in this general
>   delivery path that depend on whether a
>   gesture is recognized. You can alter
>   this delivery path to suit the
>   requirements of your application.

so... I haven't actually implemented this, but have done some reading on it... It might be a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *archivedView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cell.backgroundView];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedView];
```

you can do this by configuring the cell

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include how/why this code will solve the problem.